# Angular6 JSON schema form for Array of Items

Tags: angular6-json-schema-form

I am trying out Angular6 JSON form for my application and stuck in the issue of having array schema

The basic layout looks like

```
{
  "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "properties": {
            "type": { "type": "string" },
            "number": { "type": "string" },
        }
  },
  "layout": [
    { 
      "type": "array",
      "items": [ {
        "type": "div",
        "displayFlex": true,
        "flex-direction": "row",
        "items": [
          { "key": "type", "flex": "1 1 50px",
            "notitle": true, "placeholder": "Type"
          },
          { "key": "number", "flex": "4 4 200px",
            "notitle": true, "placeholder": "Phone Number"
          }
        ]
      } ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
      { "type": "cell", "number": "702-123-4567" },
      { "type": "work", "number": "702-987-6543" }
    ]
}
```

But I am not getting the expected outcome, that is Form is prefilled with the data

```
[
          { "type": "cell", "number": "702-123-4567" },
          { "type": "work", "number": "702-987-6543" }
        ]
```

Refer: https://hamidihamza.com/Angular6-json-schema-form/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code there are some parts you may need to revisit.

- The schema type should be either an object or boolean based on the documentation http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html
- Within the schema section, it seems that you want the type and number to be your properties of a JSON instance. Having this you can only pass one instance of data to the framework to fill in your properties because the framework cannot decide on which value to use for your property of type string.
- In case of looking for having an array of type and number, you can have a property like "phone number" with the type array. below is an example from angular6-json-schema flex layout example which I think you had as your reference.

```html
"schema": {
 ...
   "phone_numbers": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": { "type": "string", "enum": [ "cell", "home", "work" ] },
          "number": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": [ "type", "number" ]
}
```

And pass your data having something as follows:

```
"data": {
...
"phone_numbers": [
      { "type": "cell", "number": "702-123-4567" },
      { "type": "work", "number": "702-987-6543" }
    ],
}
```